# Submenu CSS dropdown menu disappears in CSS dropdown menu when mouse moves off of <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Well I am not really good in JS, but I think the only one can help solving my problam. I got sub menu with sub menu also. very simple:

```
<div class="dr_nav">
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>HOME</a>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>List Example #1</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>List Example #2</a>
       <ul>
          <li> <a href='#'>List Example Child #1</a> </li>
       </ul>
   </li> 
<li><a href='#'>List Example #3(hover)</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

BUT! The thing I want, when I hovers over my "List Example #2" and "List Example Child #1" appears (in CSS i put display:none to it) it will stay visible even if I move out my coursor from its parent "List Example #2". I hope someone can help me with this.

My CSS is a bit hard and unorganized:

```
.dr_menu
{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

.dr_menu>ul
{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.dr_menu>ul>li
{

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.dr_menu>ul>li:last-child
{

    margin:0;
}

.dr_menu ul li>ul
{

    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    top: 100%;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    width: 1400px;
}

.dr_menu ul li ul li, .dr_menu ul li ul li a
{

    padding: 10px 0px 10px 30px;
    text-align: left;

}
.dr_menu ul li ul li a
{

    display: block;
    width: 770px;
    color: #A0A0A0;
    margin-left: 300px;
}

.dr_menu ul li ul li ul
{

    display: none; 
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.dr_menu ul li ul li ul li a
{

        margin-left: 330px;
        width: 740px;
}
.dr_menu ul li ul li ul li 
{

        padding: 0;
}

.dr_menu a
{

        text-decoration: none;
        color: #A0A0A0;
}

.dr_menu>ul>li>ul>li
{

    padding-left: 0;
}

.dr_menu ul>li:hover
{

    background-image: url('./img/nav_copy.png');
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}


.dr_menu ul>li>a:hover
{

    color: white;
}

.dr_menu ul li a:hover
{

    color: white;
}

.dr_menu>ul>li>ul>li:last-child
{

    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.dr_menu li:hover>ul
{

    display: block;
    color: white;
}

.dr_menu ul li ul li a:hover
{

    background-color: #A0A0A0;
    color: black;
}
```

Here is mu JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#child').mouseleave(function() {$('#child').show()},  false);
}
```

Comment: CSS please! The HTML is fine.

Comment: What you try to archive? Looks fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/GUk8j/

Comment: LOOK) I try to achive the effect when "List Example Child #1" ONCE displayed and never hide back, untill I am surfing the rest of menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a menu with just **CSS**:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qjunz/)

```
.dr_nav li:hover>ul{
    display:block;
}
.dr_nav li>ul{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: The problam is when I hovers "List Example #3(hover)" the List Child dissapears, and I want it to stay displayed.

Comment: Hey) I need sub SUB menus display ALL the time)

Comment: Display all time?clarify

Comment: Well! its a Three level menu. So I want the third level to be displayed until the second wont be closed.I wrote some JS code, but it doesnt work and i really dont know why(